# Override parent .htaccess with php.ini?

Tags: php, apache, htaccess

Is it possible to override parent folder .htaccess rules with child php.ini or some other file except .htaccess?
What I have is:

```
/var/www/site/static/.htaccess
/var/www/site/static/abc/
/var/www/site/static/abc/def/(I have access to this)
```

I have access to `def` folder in above structure, can I override parent .htaccess rules which blocks all executable files like php, pl, py, asp, etc? How can I enable rules to execute php files in this directory without creating .htaccess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you cannot. When a `.htaccess` file blocks the execution of php, your `php.ini` won't be even read. Your problem is not the php interpreter, but the webserver config. And as you say you cannot create an own `.htaccess` file, you cannot override the config.

Comment: any comment on the other answer's suggestion? are they wrong?

Comment: No, they are not. IF you are allowed to create a .htaccess file in your directory, you possibly can override some things. But this can be disabled in the parent ``.htaccess`` file or the webserver config. And when somebody tries to disallow scripts, they probably made sure you cannot just override the limit.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can override parent .htaccess with a .htaccess file of your own. You can execute php/etc from within the .htaccess file itself. Take a look at my htshells project for some examples: https://github.com/wireghoul/htshells/

Comment: I am asking to override parent .htaccess without creating .htaccess as it's disallowed

Comment: You have a few options, get lucky and they have missed a file ext. Otherwise bug chain file upload + lfi.

Comment: @wireghoul, you don't seem very whitehat..

Comment: @pacerier lol did you even google me? Not that I need your acceptance or permission to do what I can to make the internet a better place